# mySQL table heavy usage

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, performance

I will be using mySQL with PHP as a serverside / Database model for my mobile application on both iOS and Android.

There will be loads of syncing with the client side, at a rate we assume could reach 100,000 requests to the server per second. where each one is trying to write or read from the server.

My worry is that, CAN MySQL handle this ? Does it have an internal automatic mechanism that locks the table and prevents others from writing at that exact moment when something else is already writing to the DB ? or I should take care of the myself ?

Comment: MySQL InnoDB does. But with that load, I might recommend you to consider possibility to use commercial database management systems, like MS SQL Server or Oracle. And, yeah, do yourself a favour: perform test and benchmarking.

Comment: @CORRUPT MS SQL or Oracle provide better resistance ? I heard facebook uses MySQL, and I don't think there is any company that has more traffic than facebook.

Comment: They are more stable and more reliable for such cases. MySQL doesn't even support nested transactions properly. Transactional functionality is new to MySQL for now. If you really care about your data, then you need more advanced DBMS (IMHO).

Comment: Mysql does manage synchronization and consistency so you don't have to worry about that part,however I'm not sure whether it can handle your transaction rate

Comment: facebook uses memcache and their own [flashcache](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=388112370932)

Comment: Guys do you know what is the ceiling for mySQL to accept requests before going nuts ? @djot are u reffering to me ?

Comment: @djot why not open a thread and ask the question there ? ( do not forget to add an ! there too )

Answer (score 2):

I think you need at least 64-core server (or few servers) to handle 100k transactions per second with MySQL.

And about transactions - I think you have to learn a lot about databases, table locks, transactions before you start writing your very popular application :)

Comment: @tony9099 No, I'm not.

Comment: Aiighte mate, your name looks like a one :) Anyways, I am utilizing a 64 bit server. I'll study the possibility adding couple of others and do some load balancing.

regarding the transaction, you are right, I am a noob when it comes to DB, but long live reading and coffee.